# Problem Putting Alpine Linux in Sys Mode on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, alpine-linux, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm trying to setup Alpine Linux on a Raspberry Pi Zero W in Sys Mode (normal Desktop mode) but it doesn't seem to be working.
I've followed all the instructions given on the Alpine website for installations.

After setting up the *setup-alpine* setups, I'm choosing the "Sys" mode in the mmcblk0p1 disk (SD Card). It creates a boot partition (FAT FS) then says installation is complete, please reboot. But after reboot the Alpine doesn't boot and it throws a big "Kernel Panic not Syncing" error or something like that.

I'm even having trouble installing packages as all the installations seem to be going to the RAM memory instead of ROM.

Can somebody please help me with this.
I'm not all that good with Linux systems and OS/Kernels but can learn really quick.